# Qt HTTP Request over a Unix Socket

Tags: c++, sockets, http, unix, qt5

I am using Qt5 ***QNetworkAccessManager*** to create an HTTP request. 
However I want to be able to connect to a unix socket instead of a ***http://hostname:port/***. I investigated some workarounds for this problem, and tried inheriting ***QNetworkAccessManager***, and override the ***createRequest*** virtual method, but the problem is that most of the logic for ***postProcess*** is inside the ***QNetworkReplyHttpImpl*** derived class which is fairly huge.

I have some requirements

- avoid touching the Qt5 SDK
- avoid copying too much code from the QNetworkReplyHttpImpl and implement bare bones QNetworkReply abstract class and to use the QLocalSocket.
- qhttpclient seems like an option but it will not glue nicely with the rest of the Qt5 classes, or rather I would need some more glue logic to fit with the rest of my application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A question with a similar wish: [HTTP over AF_UNIX: HTTP connection to unix socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14771172/94687)

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it though by subclassing QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply

Comment: Is your subclass to big for sharing? I was thinking into opening a local TCP socket (with QTcpServer) and then proxying it to a QLocalSocket